# Java Convert netmask to mask length

Tags: java, netmask

Is their a way to convert from a subnet: 255.255.255.0,

into mask length: 24 in Java,couldn't find a way.

i have tried using CIDR class and Inet and could not find a solution there

Comment: My network class are not from yesterday so I don't see the logic here. Why 24 again ? What have you tried ? Any API find ?

Comment: Split the IP into 4 separate sections (each octet - you should be able to split the string with the decimal point), and calculate how many bits the decimal number represents: i.e. `255 = 8 bits`, `254 = 7 bits`, or `255.255.255.0 = 8 + 8 + 8 + 0 = 24 bits`

Comment: Here's an example to do that https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-ip-address-to-decimal-number/